# How can i use this code?

Tags: php, encryption, pdo

```
session_start();
$member_username = $_POST['username']; 
$member_password = $_POST['password'];
$crypt_pass = crypt($member_password,"somesalt");

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Fatal error.";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}    

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."_users WHERE username = :user AND password = :pass");
$sth->bindParam(':user', $member_username);
$sth->bindParam(':pass', $crypt_pass);
$sth->execute();
$total = $sth->rowCount();
$row = $sth->fetch();
```

The variable `$member_password` comes from `$_POST`, but can someone explain and show how to encrypt here?

```
$crypt_pass = crypt($member_password,"somesalt");
```

Comment: Take a look here [crypt()](http://php.net//manual/en/function.crypt.php)

Comment: general tip: if you want help for a PHP function, then go to `http://php.net/name_of_function`.

Comment: You *should* forget using crypt unless you want to roll your own unique salt and hashing code, PHP 5.5's new [password_*](http://php.net/password) handles all this for you; if you dont have PHP 5.5 then you should use ircmaxell's [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The function crypt returns a hash of the password, you can not simply retrieve the original password from the hash, neither can an attacker, this way you can store the passwords in the database with optimazied security, and the more the salts complexity the more secure the hash, see http://php.net//manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 0):

`crypt` is a PHP function that takes a string and encrypts it using the DES algorithm (by default) using the given salt. This is needed because you should never store passwords without encryption or hashing, for obvious security reasons.

The salt is a (possibly random) value that you should store along with the user's information, and it's needed in order to make the encryption "more secure" (see the PHP docs for more information or google for a tutorial on how to store passwords).

Hope this helps :)